# How to convert SqlDataReader string to masked password string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

How can I convert a string that is being read by SqlDataReader to a masked password string like this: *****
I'm not trying to change an input or text box field to a type-password field, but changing the display of the string before it is displayed in a table. I have a stored procedure in a static List method that is reading the values from the DB by an ajax function that is converting the data to a jSon string before being viewed in a table.
Would it be best to mask the password from code behind, or should I be doing the masking in the javascript ajax function, or is it possible to mask the password on the table itself - in the table header field?

Method:

```
private static List<MyList> LoadData()
    {
    List<MyList> myObjects = new List<MyList>();
    //Read data from DB using SqlDataReader:
    ...
    myObjects.Password = rdr["Password"].ToString(); // Should I mask the password here?
    ...
    return myObjects;
}


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object GetData()
    {
    List<MyList> data = ModifyMember.LoadData();
    }
```

Ajax Function:

```
var Table = $('#TableId').DataTable({

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "ModifyMember.aspx/GetData",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "JSON",
        "data": function (d) {
            return d;
        },
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            json.draw = json.d.draw;
            json.recordsTotal = json.d.recordsTotal;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.d.recordsFiltered;
            json.data = json.d.data;

            var return_data = json;
            return return_data.data;
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "Password" // Should I mask the password here?
    }

});
```

Table:

```
<table id="TableId">
 <thead>
  <tr>                                    
   <th>Password</th> <%-- Or can I mask the password here --%>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: In my _opinion_, you shouldn't be using plaintext passwords anywhere, including storing them in your database. If you must do that, mask them as they leave the database and before you transmit them anywhere

Comment: I cannot think of any reason not to encrypt the password (via a one-way hash) in the application layer and use that for validation.  Store the hashed value in the database, as well.  User authentication compares the hashed password, not the plain one.  This way passwords are not compromised in the event of a physical server breach.  By the way, what does this question have to do with SQL Server, specifically?  It seems database-agnostic, to me.

Comment: @Martin I agree and normally I would use encryption, however, these are system generated passwords for non sensitive data and the administrator needs to be able to view these passwords but I still wanted a way to hide them on the table when being displayed on the screen.

Comment: @Shane If you are committed to this as a solution, I would recommend that you mask the passwords as _early as possible_. As soon as you know whether they should be masked or not, mask them. Do not do it in the presentation layer - the data layer would be best

Comment: "// Should I mask the password here?" - no, just *don't even read it*! - even in the scenario you describe, the UI shouldn't expect there to be a value there, unless you're clicking the button that exposes the secret -  so the UI can just display "********" by default; fetching the secret would of course be fully logged, such that looking at a secret records who has seen it, so you know what to rotate. And it should be fully encrypted (it sounds like it needs to be recoverable in this case, not a hash)